# jenkins-cli.jar mail command to send mail from windows command prompt

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-cli

I need help , I want to send mail from Jenkins through ANT script.
ANT script should use Jenkins mail functionality to send mail.

For that , I am using

```
java -jar E:\m\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ mail
```

Command in Windows command prompt but it is giving error ,  No recipient addresses

Can anyone tell me how to pass parameter to jenkins-cli.jar mail command in windows ?

Or is there any other method/function that I can use to send mail from ANT script using Jenkins mail functionality ????

Comment: please post the command you are using to send mail.

Comment: java -jar E:\m\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/jenkins/  mail

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Don't use ANT for the mailing process - you're already using Jenkins job to run the logic, you could use a **post build action** --> **Editable Email Notification** - and use HTML format to send beautiful messages!
2. Use (as you did) the CLI : http://${JenkinsURL}:8080/cli/command/mail - The cli is reading stdin and sends that out as an e-mail, meaning you need to insert your input during the build. you can use simple redirection from a previously created message (or generate one during the build using Ant echo into a file) and run the command as: 
   java -jar E:\m\jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/jenkins/ mail << message.txt

From The CLI : 
Reads stdin and sends that out as an e-mail.

--username VAL      : User name to authenticate yourself to Jenkins

--password VAL      : Password for authentication. Note that passing a
                       password in arguments is insecure.

--password-file VAL : File that contains the password

Comment: Do you have any logical limitation to use Jenkins to send emails?

Comment: how do you define the recipient address ?

Comment: Firstly you need to go to http://localhost:PORT/configure and edit the E-mail notification section (you can use google smtp configuration).

Then in your job you can use a post-build action called "E-mail Notification" to send emails with the job's information. 
To more advance uses I would recommend:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Answer (score 0):

`jenkins-cli.jar mail` read from stdin,
with email format text.

for example:

```
from: sender@xxx.yyy
to: receiver@xxx.zzz
subject: mail title

here is mail body
```

ctrl+d to end input (for linux; windows maybe ctrl+z).